# TFS 2015 Associate Build/Release to Manual Test Runs

Tags: tfs, tfs-2015

I'm trying to associate a test run to a release if possible, and if not then a build.

I need to either be able to associate it before the run, or after when we view the history.

I've been looking online and all I can find are references to functionality of 2017 that isn't in 2015.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not possible in TFS2015 for now. You have to upgrade your TFS server to TFS2017updae2. Detail steps please follow this tutorial: [Run automated tests from test plans in the Test hub](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/test/continuous-testing/run-automated-tests-from-test-hub)

Answer (score 1):

We are using TFS2017 Update 2, but also there it is, alas, not possible to manually run test cases against a RELEASE.
It is only possible to select a BUILD, which is not accurate in our case, because our RELEASE consists of 5 different SW components, each having it's own BUILD number.
I posted this as a feature request on the user voice forum, here: 
https://visualstudio.uservoice.com/forums/330519-visual-studio-team-services/suggestions/20579638-add-option-to-assign-a-release-version-to-a-test-r

Please vote.